# Trying to print(sum(list)) but getting error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python, list, sum

I'm trying to sum a list which has only integers in it, but I'm getting error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' in line 22. This is a 'rock paper scissors' game

```
import random
import time


score = []

while True:
    print('r/p/s')
    x=input('You: ')
    y=random.randint(1,3)
    if str(y) == '1':
        print('CPU: r')
    elif str(y) == '2':
        print('CPU: p')
    elif str(y) == '3':
        print('CPU: s')

    if x == 'r' and str(y) == '3' or x == 'p' and str(y) == '1' or x == 's' and str(y) == '2':
        print('WIN')
        score.append('1')
        print('SCORE:',end='')
        print(sum(score))
    elif x == 'r' and str(y) == '1' or x == 'p' and str(y) == '2' or x == 's' and str(y) == '3':
        print('TIE')
    elif x == 'r' and str(y) == '2' or x == 'p' and str(y) == '3' or x == 's' and str(y) == '1':
        print('LOSS')
    if input('again? (y/n) ') == 'y':
        continue
    else:
        print('     --------      ')
        print('THANKS FOR PLAYING!')
        print('     --------      ')
        time.sleep(2)
        break
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not appending integers to the array. Instead, you are appending strings with integer values!

You should do the following:

```py
import random
import time

score = []

while True:
    print('r/p/s')
    x = input('You: ')
    y = random.randint(1,3)
    if str(y) == '1':
        print('CPU: r')
    elif str(y) == '2':
        print('CPU: p')
    elif str(y) == '3':
        print('CPU: s')

    if x == 'r' and str(y) == '3' or x == 'p' and str(y) == '1' or x == 's' and str(y) == '2':
        print('WIN')
        score.append(1)
        print('SCORE:',end='')
        print(sum(score))
    elif x == 'r' and str(y) == '1' or x == 'p' and str(y) == '2' or x == 's' and str(y) == '3':
        print('TIE')
    elif x == 'r' and str(y) == '2' or x == 'p' and str(y) == '3' or x == 's' and str(y) == '1':
        print('LOSS')
    if input('again? (y/n) ') == 'y':
        continue
    else:
        print('     --------      ')
        print('THANKS FOR PLAYING!')
        print('     --------      ')
        time.sleep(2)
        break
```

Answer (score 2):

You use `score.append("1")`, adding a string to a list. Then, you use `sum(score)`, which cannot work since it now contains a string. Use `score.append(1)`

Answer (score 1):

You are appending string to list `score.append('1')` here '1' is a string do this instead `score.append(1)`